# A model similar to vector autoregressive (VAR) model with different explanatory variables

Tags: vector-autoregression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

VAR models do not allow the flexibility of having different explanatory variables in each equation.

Are there any alternative models which allow  this flexibility and written in a VAR form?

Comment: why do you think you can not have different explanatory variables in each equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can run restricted VAR models. Using a restriction matrix you can specify which variables to include for each equation. (This was the case at least in the "vars" package in R.)